# Issues backporting HAPI FHIR Server HashmapResourceProvider bug fix to a previous version

Tags: java, hapi-fhir, backport

Due to project constraints, I'm using version [6.1.0](https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir/tree/v6.1.0) of the HAPI FHIR server. However, there is a bug in that version where a resource's deletion doesn't show up as an entry in the server history. Because of this, I need to backport a fix from a future version and manually update the source code for the v6.1.0 server.

E.g.

Expected Behaviour:

```
Actions taken:
Insert Patient A
Update Patient A
Delete Patient A

History log:
Insert Patient A
Update Patient A
Delete Patient A
```

Actual Behaviour:

```
Actions taken:
Insert Patient A
Update Patient A
Delete Patient A

History log:
Insert Patient A
Update Patient A
```

I've narrowed the fix down to the `ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.provider.HashmapResourceProvider` in the `hapi-fhir-server` package in this [commit](https://github.com/hapifhir/hapi-fhir/pull/4456/commits/3f631840783e62ec884028492353ad55e67835c6) and replaced the `HashmapResourceProvider` code used with the newer one.

To make the new code compatible with the older server, I modified the way resources are provided for `ResourceMetadataKeyEnum`.
E.g.

```
// Bug fix code
ResourceMetadataKeyEnum.DELETED_AT.get(nextResource)

// Modified code to make compatible with v6.1.0 server.
ResourceMetadataKeyEnum.DELETED_AT.get((IAnyResource) nextResource)
```

The problem is that now, when a resource is deleted, the entire history of that resource doesn't appear in the server history any more.

Is there anything I am missing that is causing this issue?